# Add time to timestamps with PHP?

Tags: php, foreach, str-replace

I have some files which have timestamps in their content, that are not accurate enough.

So, I was thinking, could PHP convert a non-fixed amount of timestamps to accurate ones, while not touching the other content.

For example, convert this

> 1 00:00:00,232 --> 00:00:05,665 Text1
>
> 2 00:00:05,966 --> 00:00:08,909 Text2
>
> 3 00:00:10,948 --> 00:00:14,550 Text3
>
> 4 00:00:23,086 --> 00:00:25,817 Text4
>
> 5 00:00:34,033 --> 00:00:35,847 Text5
>
> 6 00:01:06,237 --> 00:01:07,716 Text6

to this

> 1 00:00:00,732 --> 00:00:06,165 Text1
>
> 2 00:00:06,466 --> 00:00:09,409 Text2
>
> 3 00:00:11,448 --> 00:00:15,050 Text3
>
> 4 00:00:23,586 --> 00:00:26,317 Text4
>
> 5 00:00:34,533 --> 00:00:36,347 Text5
>
> 6 00:01:06,737 --> 00:01:08,216 Text6

So on this case, add 0.5sec to every timestamp. I know it's possible, but how?

```
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$content = $_POST['text'];
$timestamp = ?
$newtime = $timestamp.$amount
$replacetime = str_replace($timestamp,$newtime,$content);
foreach(what to put here){
$replacetime;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to parse a subtitle file? Read the file first. Then parse it.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im File is being read on $content, but I'm wondering how to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to shift the time to the subtitle. Though it can be done by the video player you can still do it in PHP.

First read the file.

```
$c = file_get_contents("...file.srt");
```

Extract the contents

```
preg_match_all("|(\d+)[\r\n]+([\d,:]+) --> ([\d,:]+)[\r\n]+(.*)|", $c, $m);
```

Now add `0.5` seconds for each of the times

```
$len = count($m[1]);
for($i=0;$i<$len; $i++){
    list($st, $sm)=explode(",", $m[2][$i]); // start time and milisecond
    // add 0.5 sec
    $sm+=500;
    if($sm>1000){
        $di = new DateInterval("P0000-00-00T$st");
        $di->add("P1S");
        $sm = $sm%1000;
        $st = $di->format("%H:%i:%s");
    }
    // store it back
    $m[2][$i] = "$st,$sm";
}
```

Same way you have to do for end time. You can do it in the same loop too.

After that put it back to original file. Try other file to test first

```
for($i=0;$i<$len; $i++){
    fprintf($fh, "$m[1][$i]\n");
    fprintf($fh, "$m[2][$i] --> $m[3][$i]\n");
    fprintf($fh, "$m[3][$i]\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Nice! I think. I'll modify this a bit for it to meet my purpose, would you check it's okay then?

Comment: Its okay. But you have to test it. This is the idea. Not complete solution.

Comment: My version will only create a internal server error, what could be wrong?

Comment: And yours will simply write the file with blank :P Could you break your code to parts I could easily understand? :)